# Sort by date instead of day. PHP or PHPUnit

Tags: php

$dates = array(dates from below);

How would I sort this array by month, day, year, then by the timestamp shown below?

```
Array (
0 => 'Thu Aug 30 2012 14:38:13 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
1 => 'Thu Aug 30 2012 14:53:13 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
2 => 'Thu Aug 30 2012 14:57:42 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
3 => 'Thu Aug 30 2012 14:58:34 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
4 => 'Thu Aug 30 2012 14:59:21 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
5 => 'Thu Aug 30 2012 15:00:11 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
6 => 'Thu Aug 30 2012 15:01:25 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
7 => 'Thu Aug 30 2012 15:03:15 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
8 => 'Thu Aug 30 2012 15:05:56 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
9 => 'Thu Aug 30 2012 15:06:50 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
10 => 'Thu Aug 30 2012 15:09:06 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
11 => 'Thu Aug 30 2012 15:11:32 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
12 => 'Thu Aug 30 2012 15:20:26 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
13 => 'Thu Aug 30 2012 15:21:12 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
14 => 'Thu Aug 30 2012 15:22:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
15 => 'Thu Aug 30 2012 15:22:58 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
16 => 'Thu Aug 30 2012 15:24:34 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
17 => 'Thu Aug 30 2012 15:25:35 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
18 => 'Thu Aug 30 2012 15:26:48 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
19 => 'Wed Sep 19 2012 09:42:57 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
20 => 'Fri Oct 05 2012 10:11:28 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
21 => 'Wed Oct 10 2012 11:27:15 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
);
```

Answer (score 1):

strtotime() to convert each time into a unix timestamp, then date('Y-m-d H:i:s') to sort by date

for example:

```
$unix =  strtotime('Thu Aug 30 2012 14:38:13 GMT-0700 (PDT)');

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $unix);
```

will output:

```
2012-10-11 15:25:42
```

Which you can sort on

Comment: Sorry forgot to send the $unix timestamp into the date function, its updated to reflect that now

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better solution, but this should work:

```
foreach ($dates as $value) {
    $newDates[strtotime($value)] = $value;
}

$newDates = ksort($newDates);
```

This will make the new array `$newDates` have a key of a timestamp and sort by the key.  This will maintain the value of your array in the format you already have it.  If you would like to change the format, you can do something like:

```
$newDates[strtotime($value)) = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($value)); // 2012-11-10 12:27:00
```